# How do I change the color only once upon mousePressed (stop it from cycling)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm working on another tutorial for practice and my program is supposed to change the eye color once when you hold down the mouse. But when I try holding it down, it continuously cycles through random colors instead of just changing once. Essentially, I want to only change the eye color once each time the user presses or holds down the mouse.

```
var u;
var l;
var a;
var mods = [];
var x;
var y;
var count;
var r, g, b;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  u = 100;
  l = 40;
  var highCount = height/80;
  var wideCount = width/80;
  count = int(highCount * wideCount);

  var index = 0;
  for (var xc = 0; xc < wideCount; xc++) {
    for (var yc = 0; yc < highCount; yc++) {
      mods[index++] = new Module(int(xc)*u,int(yc)*u);
    }
   }
}

function draw() {
  //background black if mouse is pressed or held down
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    background(0);
    r = random(255);
    g = random(255);
    b = random(255);
  //background white if mouse is not pressed or held down
  } else {
    background(255);
  }
  //drawing the eyeballs
  noStroke();
  translate(15, 15);
  for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    mods[i].update();
    mods[i].eyeball();
    mods[i].pupil();
  }
}

function Module(_x, _y) {
  this.x = _x;
  this.y = _y;
  this.a = 0;
}

Module.prototype.update = function() {
    this.a = atan2(mouseY-this.y, mouseX-this.x);
}

Module.prototype.eyeball = function() {
  push();
  translate(this.x, this.y);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(0, 0, l, l);
  pop();
}

//need to keep pupil and iris together for movement
Module.prototype.pupil = function() {
  push();
  translate(this.x, this.y);
  rotate(this.a);
  fill(r, g, b);
  ellipse(8, 0, l/2, l/2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(8, 0, l/4, l/4);
  pop();
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the [draw()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) function continuously executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the program is stopped or noLoop() is called

In your code it was continuously changing the values of `r`, `g`, and `b`

You would rather need to use [mousePressed](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) event instead.

P.S. I declared initial random colors in `setup()` so that it not complaining: `p5.js says: color() was expecting Number`

```js
var u;
var l;
var a;
var mods = [];
var x;
var y;
var count;
var r, g, b;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  //initial color
  r = random(255);
  g = random(255);
  b = random(255);
  
  u = 100;
  l = 40;
  var highCount = height/80;
  var wideCount = width/80;
  count = int(highCount * wideCount);

  var index = 0;
  for (var xc = 0; xc < wideCount; xc++) {
    for (var yc = 0; yc < highCount; yc++) {
      mods[index++] = new Module(int(xc)*u,int(yc)*u);
    }
   }
}

function draw() {
  //background black if mouse is pressed or held down
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    background(0);
    //r = random(255);
    //g = random(255);
    //b = random(255);
  //background white if mouse is not pressed or held down
  } else {
    background(255);
  }
  //drawing the eyeballs
  noStroke();
  translate(15, 15);
  for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    mods[i].update();
    mods[i].eyeball();
    mods[i].pupil();
  }
}

// HERE WE ARE
function mousePressed() {
  r = random(255);
  g = random(255);
  b = random(255);
}

function Module(_x, _y) {
  this.x = _x;
  this.y = _y;
  this.a = 0;
}

Module.prototype.update = function() {
    this.a = atan2(mouseY-this.y, mouseX-this.x);
}

Module.prototype.eyeball = function() {
  push();
  translate(this.x, this.y);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(0, 0, l, l);
  pop();
}

//need to keep pupil and iris together for movement
Module.prototype.pupil = function() {
  push();
  translate(this.x, this.y);
  rotate(this.a);
  fill(r, g, b);
  ellipse(8, 0, l/2, l/2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(8, 0, l/4, l/4);
  pop();
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I had no idea that the draw function continuously executes the code inside of it, thanks again! This makes a lot more sense now :)